# Are qsort and quick sort both same?

Tags: c, sorting

I am confused between qsort and quick sort. Are they both same ? If no then  how do they differ from each other ?

Comment: @rob.alarcon Probably because it (in the words of the downvote button) "does not show research effort".

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=quick+sort+qsort&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @rob.alarcon - I am assuming they due to the complete lack of research that this question demonstrates.

Comment: @rob.alarcon I am also surprised

Comment: ok, question guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Quicksort gained widespread adoption, appearing, for example, in Unix as the default library sort function, hence it lent its name to the C standard library function qsort and in the reference implementation of Java. (See history) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they aren't. [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) is a C standard library function. ["Quicksort"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), on the other hand, is a specific sorting **algorithm.** It is often used as the backing algorithm of an actual implementation of `qsort()`.